# Pass null variable to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

I want to pass a value (1) to my controller as you can see :

```
<input id="myButton2" type="button" value="Call Controller Method" onclick="myff('1');"  />
```

Script:

```
function myff(re) {
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("MyControllerMethod","Reception",new {  area ="Admin"})', function (data) {
    refid = re;
  });
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public JsonResult MyControllerMethod(string refid) {
  return Json("Controller Method call", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But when I clicked the button the action is fired but the `refid` in my action is null why ?

Comment: You have not passed he value to the controller - `$.getJSON('@Url.Action(...)', { refid: re }function (data) {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke so how can i pass the value ?

Comment: As per my comment - you pass it in the 2nd argument of `getJSON` as an object

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed to this ,but return null again     $.getJSON('@Url.Action("MyControllerMethod","Reception",new {  area ="Admin"})', { refid: re },function (data) {
                   refid = re;
        });

Comment: That works fine (but the `{ refid = re; }` in the callback makes no sense. But you really need to stop polluting your markup with behavior and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right it was my fault .it works thank you

Comment: @StephenMuecke post you answer to mark as  correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value in the 2nd argument of `$.getJSON()`

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MyControllerMethod","Reception",new { area ="Admin"})';
$.getJSON(url, { refid: re }, function (data) {
    console.log(data); // returns "Controller Method call"
});
```

I also recommend you use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting markup with behavior

```
<input id="myButton2" type="button" data-x="1" value="Call Controller Method" />

$('#myButton2.click(function) {
    var re = $(this).data('x');
    $.getJSON(.....
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$.getJSON()`, try this code:

```
function myff(re) {
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: '@Url.Action("MyControllerMethod","Reception",new {  area ="Admin"})',
  data: {refid : re}
});
```

**Note**: Although `$.getJSON()` calls internally `$.ajax()` but the latter one gives you more flexibility- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I changed to this , <script>
       function myff(re) {
           $.ajax({
               dataType: "json",
               url: '@Url.Action("MyControllerMethod","Reception",new {  area ="Admin"})',
               data: {refid : re},
               success //to do
       });

       }
</script>but my controller doesn't fire

Comment: Removed the success prameter. Try the updated answer.